# JQuery find parent div child label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i click on **expandable-icons-cancel** I want to save a child label of **form-group** div.
Here is the structure:

```
<div class="form-group ">
 <label class="" style="padding-top:10px;"> Long Title</label>
 <span class="value ">
  <div class="expandable">
   <div class="expandable-icons">
    <img class="expandable-icons-cancel" style="display:none;" src="test/cancel.png">
   </div>
  </div>
 </span>
</div>
```

And function:

```
jQuery('.expandable-icons-cancel').click(function() {
  var parentDiv = jQuery(this).parents('div.expandable'); //-works, but how can i get upper? 
  // How to get 2 steps upper to form-group?
  // How to get get child label text of form-group and save in var?
 }
```

Comment: [Here the best ressource.](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), like this

```
jQuery(this).closest(".form-group");
```

for the label text you can do...

```
jQuery(this).closest(".form-group").find("label").text();
```

if you know label will always be a direct child of `.form-group`, you can use `children()` in place of `find()`. If there is a possible for multiple labels and you only want to get the first, you can place `eq(0)` after getting the label.